# What does NOR actually mean?

Tags: logic

I am having trouble understanding what nor means. If we have the sentence I don't like chocolate nor vanilla, that means you don't like both and not just one right? Or let's say we had neither a left nor b left, does that mean neither a nor b both left? My question basicaIly is what does nor actually mean? Is it inclusive only or exclusive? Iam not a native English speaker so this has been troubling me for a few hours now, please help thanks

Comment: It means you negate both objects in the statement; neither $A$ nor $B$ means not $A$ and not $B$.

Comment: "I don't like **neither** chocolate **nor** vanilla."

Answer (score 2):

NOR is the negation of inclusive OR

While  OR means either one or both, NOR means none of them.

Neither Jack NOR Jill were at the party means none of them were at the party.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you a lot Moh

Answer (score 0):

$A$ nor $B$ is equivalent to not $A$ and not $B$ by [DeMorgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Answer (score 0):

"NOR" means deny the disjunction, that is, if $\phi$ and $\psi$ are propositions:
$$\neg(\phi\vee \psi)$$
which is equivalent to
$$(\neg\phi)\wedge (\neg\psi)$$